# Cloudera MapReduce Counter getValue Error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I'm currently working on a MapReduce map-only program with Counters on Cloudera. The Mapper class will increment a specific Counter, and i want to display every Counter's final value after the MapReduce job is done. Below is my Mapper class code:

```java
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    public static enum MY_COUNTER {
        C1,
        C2
    }

    //mapper logic that produces String variable 'final'

    if (final.equals("Foo")) context.getCounter(MY_COUNTER.C1).increment(1);
    else context.getCounter(MY_COUNTER.C2).increment(1);

    //context.write() method
}
```

And below is my Driver class code:

```java
public class MyDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MyDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "My MapReduce");

        //Job configuration:
        //Sets mapper to MyMapper class
        //Sets num of Reduce tasks to 0
        //Other necessary job config

        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        if (success) {
            Counter counter1 = job.getCounters().findCounter("MY_COUNTER", "C1");
            System.out.println(counter1.getDisplayName() + ": " + counter1.getValue());
            Counter counter2 = job.getCounters().findCounter("MY_COUNTER", "C2");
            System.out.println(counter2.getDisplayName() + ": " + counter2.getValue());
            return 0;
        }
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

When i run the jar file, The job successfully executed. Because i set the `job.waitForCompletion()` parameter to true, it prints all the MapReduce progress to the terminal. I can see the my counter's value from there.

```
18/03/27 09:59:58 INFO mapreduceJob: Counters: 35

    //all built-in counters

    MyMapper$MY_COUNTER
        C1=837
        C2=119
```

But, when i print the counter's value after the job is done (from the `if(success)` part of MyDriver class), the printed values are all zeros.

```
C1: 0
C2: 0
```

Any suggestions on where i might be wrong?

Note: I'm using Hadoop `2.6.0-cdh5.12.0`

Comment: I am using similar code and it works fine. Except, I use `context.getCounter("MY_COUNTER", "C1").increment(1);` Try that if it works.

Comment: @Amita That works! With that, i don't even need to make an enum for my counter inside my Mapper class. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I should increment the counter using string parameter instead of enum. The increment process will be like:

```java
context.getCounter("MY_COUNTER","C1").increment(1);
```

With that, i don't even need to declare an enum for my counter at my Mapper class. Thanks to [Amita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858467/amita) for helping me out.